# How to deserialize to a dynamic type

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to de-serialize my XML to get an array of a type which is created dynamically (using codedom) and after that I am using reflection to load that assembly and loading the type which is created dynamically. When I try to de-serialize my XML (which has got a collection of objects of this dynamically generated type) I am not sure how do I provide the type to the serializer.

**My code sample:**

```
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("myDynamicassembly.dll");
        Type type = assembly.GetType("myDynamicType");

        string xmlstring = myXml.OuterXml.ToString();
        byte[] buffer = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlstring);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(ms);

        myDynamicType[] EQs;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myDynamicType[]));
        EQs = (myDynamicType[])(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
```

So, here the problem is that I don't know the "myDynamicType" while writing the code. It will be created and compiled at runtime.

Please help.

Comment: Do you know the types in compile time though, or are you loading assemblies which are totally unknown? How are you going to use these objects?

Comment: No, I don't know the type at compile time. Actually, it will be generated and compiled to an assembly at runtime. So, you can say that my assembly as well as my 'myDynamicType' both are totally unknown at compile time. As far as the further use is concerned, I am going to pass this array to my web service which will execute some operation on this collection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick here is the `Type.MakeArrayType()` method on an instance of `Type`. The parameterless version produces the *vector* type, i.e. `typeof(Foo).MakeArrayType()` === `typeof(Foo[])`. There are other overloads for multi-dimensional arrays etc.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(type.MakeArrayType());
```

However: you will *not* be able to cast it at the end; you will need to use `object[]` or similar (using array variance of reference-types):

```
EQs = (object[])(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. But, if I cast it to object[] I would not be able to pass it to the web service which expects a collection of a specific type.

Comment: @AshishAgrawal If the type is loaded dynamically, you already have a problem there. It is fundamentally *of* that type regardless of how you type it. If the type is known statically, then frankly all of this is pointless.

Comment: type is not defined statically. Actually, as I said, I am using codedom to create "myDynamicType". So, this string is variable that would change based on some input from the user. So for example, if user says I want to create a Student class then my code would change to something like :                                                Student[] EQs;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new     XmlSerializer(typeof(Student[]));
        EQs = (Student[])(serializer.Deserialize(reader));                     Please let me know if I am creating any confusion here.

Comment: @AshishAgrawal the problem is the last bit - the EQs. It is hard to do anything useful with a variable that isn't (and CANNOT be) statically typed. You either need to use reflection or `dynamic`.

Comment: let me try and explain my exact requirement here. I have a web service which generates the wsdl dynamically based on the information provided by the client (via url). For example, if user tries to access "myServiceHost/myWebService/A.asmx?wsdl"; then the wsdl shows some methods like GetA(A[] records), CreateA(A[] records), DeleteA(A[] records) etc. Where A would be a serializable type. Suppose if the user tries and accesses the url myServiceHost/myWebService/B.asmx?wsdl, then it would show some methods like GetB(B[] records), CreateB(B[] records), DeleteB(B[] records) contd

Comment: So, in my client code instead of creating the proxy class by wsdl.exe tool (because I do not want to add so many proxy classes for each and every possible wsdl) I am creating the proxy class dynamically in the code (based on the url) using codedom and compiling it to an assembly and then using reflection to get the type of my concern. Now, in order to invoke a method, say CreateA(A[] records), I need to deserialize my xml (having serialized objects of A) to get a collection of A. But I am not sure if it is possible to provide the type to the serializer dynamically (as mentioned in my question)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what i'm going to say is what you want but:

can't you deserialize it as an object type

```
object[] EQs;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(object[]));
EQs = (object[])(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
```

If the object type is defined on compile time (as you say) shouldn't there be a bit of code which defines it? and in that piece of code you simply convert the object to the type you want?

An other way to convert once you have your `object[] EQs` is the following:

```
     if(EQs.Lenght > 0)
     {
        Type t = EQs[0].GetType();
     }
```

and now use the gained `Type` to convert your `object[] EQs` to the right `Type`

Comment: "can't you deserialize it as an object type" - no, basically; `XmlSerializer` needs to know what it should expect

Comment: @Vincent, actually I am creating that type dynamically (at runtime) using codedom. Here is the code where I am getting the type at runtime (based on the input from the user).                                  Type type = assembly.GetType("myDynamicType");                                                              So, myDynamicType is not a statically defined type.

Comment: so what types can it be? ar we talking about it could be strings it could be numbers. Or it could be custom clases.
and more importantly, do you need to calculate/do stuff with it? if it's just for loading from xml to display somewere on a a screen a string would suffice.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat it can be any custom type and will contain several methods (please see my comment to Marc's answer above). I will be passing this collection to my web service (to do some operations over that collection).